# Method for calculating percentage for a value between two bounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

I have the following calculation to make:

```
float value = MY_VALUE;

float percentage = (value - MIN)/(MAX - MIN);
if (percentage < 0)
   percentage = 0;
if (percentage > 1)
   percentage = 1
```

I was just wondering if there is some method that exists in Objective-C or C to help accomplish this, like for example a method that will round the "value" float to be between the MIN and MAX bounds.

Comment: Good to ask the question rather than just plough ahead writing your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

On another note, you should probably update your code so you are preventing a possible divide-by-zero:

```
float den = (value - MIN);
float num = (MAX - MIN);
float percentage;

if(den) {
  percentage = num / den;
  if (percentage < 0.0f ) {
    percentage = 0.0f;
  } else if (percentage > 1.0f) {
    percentage = 1.0f;
  } else {
    printf("Percentage: %3.2f",percentage);
  }
} else {
  percentage = 0.0f;
  printf("DIVIDE BY ZERO ERROR!");
}
```

Also, careful. Oracle is suing Google over a very similar piece of code. You may want to reconsider posting it publicly:

http://developers.slashdot.org/story/12/05/16/1612228/judge-to-oracle-a-high-schooler-could-write-rangecheck

Comment: The patent claims just got rejected (today: see [GrokLaw](http://www.groklaw.net/article.php?story=20120523125023818)).  Besides, that was 9 lines of Java, not 6 lines of Objective C.  Though that might have been from the copyright phase, not the patent phase.  And 9 lines out of umpteen million should be de minimis.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for the ridiculous patent story, I can add it to my collection.

Comment: "9 lines out of umpteen million should be de minimis"... Not according to the U.S. courts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_America,_Inc._v._Google,_Inc.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such method in standard C libraries (I don't know about Objective C).

Comment: that depends on what the question is... by juding the code he could use MIN(a,b) and MAX(a,b)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate percentage in objective-c syntax then this is the way to go.

(I think Dogbert got it wrong (opposite) on line 6).
Here's what I did and it works just as wanted..

```
- (CGFloat)calculateProgressForValue:(CGFloat)value start:(CGFloat)start end:(CGFloat)end
{    
    CGFloat diff = (value - start);
    CGFloat scope = (end - start);
    CGFloat progress;

    if(diff != 0.0) {
        progress = diff / scope;
    } else {
        progress = 0.0f;
    }

    return progress;
}
```

And you can always constrain this to not go over 0.0 or 1.0 like so:

```
- (CGFloat)progressConstrained {

    // example values
    CGFloat start = 80;
    CGFloat end = 160;
    CGFloat a = 100;

    // the constrain
    return MAX(0.0, MIN(1.0, [self calculateProgressForValue:a start:start end:end]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make sure a value is not higher or lower than other values you should use MAX(a, b) and MIN(a, b)...

```
float maxValue = 1.0;
float minValue = 0.0;
float myValue = 2.8;
float myValueConstrained = MAX(minValue, MIN(maxValue, myValue)); // 1.0
```

MIN(a,b) takes the smallest of a and b

MAX(a,b) takes the greatest of a and b

---

I typically just do like this:

```
float myValueConstrained = MAX(0.0, MIN(1.0, myValue));
```